# WCF Service : how can I use shared classes?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an ASP.NET project that exposes multiple WCF Services.
Most these services make use of common custom classes in the APP_Code folder used throughout the project.

Consuming these WCF services is a console app I have written.

My question is :-

In the console app I obviously instantiate each of the WCF services I'm using - but some of these services utilise the common classes as parameters to some of the methods.

However on the client side (console app) - those classes are exposed exclusively as part of that WCF Service's namespace and not interchangeable)

Example of syntax error is something like :-

**cannot convert from 'ManagementAgent.Computer_ServiceReference.ComputerIdentity' to 'ManagementAgent.WorkloadAnalysis_ServiceReference.ComputerIdentity'.**

The class "ComputerIdentity" is a commonly shared class in the App_Code folder.

How do I get this class interchangeable as a parameter across multiple WCF Services?

Comment: Consider putting those clases into a separate project and then into a separate class library. Share this. Finished.

Answer (score 0):

Your shared classes need to come from the same *assembly*, not just shared code. Put the classes you want to share into their own class library and reference that in all projects.

Comment: Thanks - Tried that - presents the same issue - despite me including the same class library in both projects. Still get a "cannot convert from ..." syntax error.

This time between the locally referenced class and the WCF service class (Same class)

Comment: @Cyclone_ZA Why is there a "locally referenced class"? You should use the same class from the same assembly on both ends.